# Conversion of Word Document into HTML using interop

Tags: c#, html, interop, ms-office

I know there is a feature of interop to save the word document into HTML.

But my problem is it doesn't save the Column as Column.

This is the screenshot of my document

[image]

And this is the output when saved as HTML

[image]

so what i'm thinking is traverse the word document. Check if the Object is column, then parse the text and create a column in html output.

The reason why i'm doing it this way because i have a guidelines to follow in converting the Word to Html.

How can i traverse the word document? I am parsing the words in document and i have a problem getting the format for each word

```
                Application ap = new Application();
                Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"doc sample.doc");

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in document.Paragraphs)
                {
                    string pText = paragraph.Range.Text;
                    Console.WriteLine("BOLD: " + paragraph.Range.Font.Bold);
                    Console.WriteLine(pText);
                }
                document.Close();
                ap.Quit();
```

The output of the code is

```
BOLD: 9999999 
And the text of the paragraph.
```

But not all text in that paragraph is BOLD. How can i check the format of each word in a paragraph?

And is it possible to check if the Word has columns, tables, shapes, images, and parse the words in columns, tables?

Thank you.